# Express app closing after any connection request after adding Redis to it

Tags: node.js, express, session, redis, express-session

So, I have just added Redis to my expressjs app (this is the first time I use redis), and this is all I did to add the Redis:

```
import express, { Application } from 'express';
import session from 'express-session';
import {createClient} from 'redis';
import connectRedis from 'connect-redis'

const app: Application = express();
const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
const redisClient = createClient({
    url: 'redis://localhost:6379'
});

app.use(session({
    secret: SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }), // added this line
    cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 2,
        httpOnly: false,
        secure: false,
    }
}));

export default app;
```

But when I make any request to any of my express routes, I get an instant error on console, and the app is closed for any further requests. This is the error:
[image]

As you can see, there is a line `Server is listening on port 3000` at the top of the screenshot, the rest of the strings appears only when I make the first request to the api.

What am I missing here, what did I do wrong? Because every video/article on internet has the same exact code...

Comment: What node and Redis version are you using?

Comment: Hi @ApoorvaChikara , the Node version is v16.13.0, redis version is ^4.0.1 and connect-redis ^6.0.0

Comment: @JoãoCasarin as you can see [here](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis#redisstoreoptions), connect-redis does not support node-redis v4 (yet)

Comment: Hey @LeibaleEidelman just checked here and apparently that's it! I tried with node-redis v3.1.2 and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as noticed by @Apoorva Chikara and mentioned by @Leibale Eidelman , `connect-redis` does not support latest `node-redis` yet, so to fix it I just downgraded my `redis` package to the version `3.1.2` by using `$ yarn add redis@3.1.2`.

Thanks!